# How to find all files in all subdirectories in python

Tags: pandas, glob, os.walk

I want to return a list of ALL files located from a certain point.

I am using python.

Currently,

```
import os
import pandas as pd
path='c://users.../'

f=[]
for currentpath, folders, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
#         print(os.path.join(currentpath, file))
        f.append(file)

df=pd.DataFrame(f)
df.columns=['file_name']
print(df.shape)
df
```

works fine, but I have ~70k files in ~10k subfolders/directories, and it is incredibly slow.

I heard glob.glob() is quicker, but:

```
import glob
root_dir='c://users/.../'
for filename in glob.iglob(root_dir + '**/*', recursive=True):
     print(filename)
```

But this only returns the names of subfolders.

Is there a quick way to compile this into a file for future processing.

Comment: did you get around to solving this?

Comment: I ended up using os.walk and let it run over night. Took 6 hours

Comment: Damn, well atleast it's done!

Answer (score 0):

you can use pathlib to speed up this operation which uses `scandir` under the hood which is much quicker than the operation you are using

https://pypi.org/project/scandir/

```
from Pathlib import Path
def tree(directory):
    print(f'+ {directory}')
    for path in sorted(directory.rglob('*')):
        depth = len(path.relative_to(directory).parts)
        spacer = '    ' * depth
        print(f'{spacer}+ {path.name}')

tree(path) # will print out your directory tree.
```

if you want to append you can do

```
files = [file for file in Path(path).rglob('*')]
```